# Visual Studio help system targets wrong framework version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msdn

Sometimes, when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> in Visual Studio Code Editor, it opens browser with MSDN page for .NET **Micro** Framework. My projects are using .NET Framework 4.5 and there is no trace of Micro Framework in them.

For example pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> over `MulticastDelegate` in my code editor opens [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.MulticastDelegate);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) instead of [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.aspx).

Anybody has the same issues?

**UPDATE:**
As Jeff Braaten suggested, I checked Debug help context and it seems fine. There is no difference (except the keyword) between context for `Action` and `MulticastDelegate`, for example.

And the same tells generated URL
For `Action`:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1
&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Action);
k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);
k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true
```

For `MulticastDelegate`:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1
&l=EN-US&k=k(System.MulticastDelegate);
k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);
k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true
```

So, most likely, it's not how VS generates request, it's how MSDN search engine interprets it.

Comment: are you using offline or online help?

Comment: I'm using framework 4.0 and it opened a right page i.e for 4.0

Comment: i tried to change `v4.5` to `v4.0` in the link vs generated and now it opens:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.multicastdelegate(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: changing setting `Help -> Change Help Preference` to `Launch in HelpViewer` leads to opening correct link in help viewer

Comment: You may want to check out the TargetFrameworkMoniker in your [Debug Help Context](http://thirdblogfromthesun.com/2013/01/debug-visual-studio-f1-help/).

Comment: @JeffBraaten `TargetFrameworkMoniker=.NETFramework,Version=v4.5` but still thanks, i didn't know that stuff. I thing the problem is on the MS's end because url is passed right, it's just the results for 4.5 are wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known issue with F1 and Visual Studio 2012. We are working on it, and there is no workaround at this time. For now, you'll need to use search to find the correct topic. Robin Reynolds-Haertle, Documentation Manager

Comment: Thanks, can i track a state of the issue somewhere?

Comment: Ditto Anri's comment.  13 months later I'm still having this problem in an entirely different version of VS.

Comment: As per @pbarranis this is STILL BROKEN in VS2013. [There is a Connect bug for this issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816618/f1-shows-api-reference-for-net-micro-framework), I encourage everyone experiencing this to vote on that bug and hopefully get Microsoft to fix it before the next Visual Studio comes out.

Comment: Looks like Microsoft has chosen not to fix this bug; the Connect bug  referenced by @Ian Kemp is closed as of 12/18/2014.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that Visual Studio is incorrectly building the Version key-value pair with a `=` instead of `-`, which then gets converted to `%3D` when the address is [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

If you replace the `%3D` in this section of the URL

```
 k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);
```

with a `-`, you get the correct [.NET Framework 4.5 MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.MulticastDelegate);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version-v4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).

So, the correct address for `MulticastDelegate` would be:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1
&l=EN-US&k=k(System.MulticastDelegate);
k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version-v4.5);
k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true
```

Comment: Nice find, but it appears that fixing this issue with a Windows Update that changes = to - is beyond Microsoft's capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been a long-standing issue with F1 and Visual Studio, but this has been finally fixed. So now, when you press F1 in Visual Studio, MSDN should open the right topic for you.

Comment: Can you link to a version changelist or other documentation around this fix? Also, can you please note that version at which this fix should be first noticeable?

Comment: There's no version changelist for this fix because this was a fix to the MSDN website and its content pages (like key metadata information missing). The pages for .NET Framework 4.5 and 4.6 have been recently republished, so now MSDN can find the right page when someone presses F1.
Since the problem posted originally no longer reproduces, I'm not sure how I could possibly answer the question differently. Why an answer that says we're working on a fix is acceptable but an answer that says this is fixed is not?

Comment: And this is the Connect bug that was being tracked for this work: [Connect bug 1312747](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1312747/f1-in-vs-shows-documentation-for-the-wrong-target-framework-e-g-micro-framework)